# Как в Tor сделать смену ip адреса каждые 30 секунд?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, tor

Нужно написать скрипт для смены ip tor каждые 30 секунд, в интернете нашел буквально один код, изменил принты под python 3.x и... socket error

**Код:**

[image: Часть 1]
[image: Часть 2]
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Вы шлёте request, меняете ip и ожидаете после этого получить назад response?

Comment: Я получаю ответ после чека ip, после меняю ip и снова и так далее

Comment: @root, пожалуйста, замените фотографии на код в виде `текста`

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Для смены ip нужно в `torrc` задавать настройки, давно такое делал попробуйте: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6863c924f57bed4dc5b3c82419d84d32d2fd0453/using_tor/loop_check_url.py#L17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы. Во-первых нам нужно установить хеш-пароль, для этого хешируем пароль

```
tor --hash-password вашпарольвместоVallio338
```

Хэшированный пароль, сгенерированный выше, должен храниться внутри переменной HashedControlPassword файла torrc:

```
nano /etc/tor/torrc
```

Далее находим следующие строчки:
[image: Комментарии для поиска]

И делаем так:
[image: Пример фото]

Где вы пишете свой хеш так:

```
HashedControlPassword вашхешсюда
```

Далее находим строчки:

```
#TransPort 9040

#ControlPort 9051
```

И делаем вот так, тем самым активируя их:

```
TransPort 9040

ControlPort 9051
```

Далее нажимаем Ctrl + O, чтобы сохранить файл, подтверждаем Enter и при необходимости с помощью Ctrl + x выходим из редактора. Далее запускаем скрипт и он работает!